# Vagrant can not access the box over HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: vagrant, basic-authentication, vagrantfile

`Vagrant up` can access and download my Vagrant box (that I packed and placed on my hosting) by `http://devops.example.com/vagrant.box`. 
**But** I do not want my box to be public, and want to protect is by using HTTP Basic Auth. 
When I turn on Basic Auth and do 'vagrant up', Vagrant returns message with 401 error.

**How can I configure Vagrant, so it can access the box over Basic Auth?**

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For HTTP Basic Authentication, you can do (from Vagrant 1.8)

```
vagrant box add <box> http://user:pass@devops.example.com/vagrant.box
```

In some older version of vagrant, the following is working

```
vagrant box add <box> http://devops.example.com/vagrant.box -u user:pass
```

If you distribute your box on [vagrantcloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com) you can enable better authentication, you can review https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/vagrant/boxes/distributing

Comment: Thank you for helping. Let me try the concept, as I am using the Vagrant file that maps the JSON file instruction, where I have `"url": "http://devops.example.com/vagrant.box"`. I will let you know If it works or not.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore: `An invalid option was specified.`

Comment: @static_rtti did you try both option ?

Comment: Oh, I just saw your second option, it works. I think you should remove the first one.

Comment: @static_rtti yep it was working still in some older version of vagrant, not sure exactly when they stop supporting it

Comment: The http://user:pass@hostname/boxname.box approach works with Vagrant 1.8.6. Though, special characters that are not compliant with with vagrants rfc3986_parser.rb. result in a not recognized download URI. In my case a password containing the / characater breaks functionality. Not sure if this is a bug or wanted behavior.